# Center triangle at bottom of div full width responsively

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, css-shapes

After hours of trying in CSS (sorry, I'm still a CSS noob) I am asking you for help:
I want a triangle to be the "bottom" of a div while filling the whole screen width, no matter what size the screen is (100%).
When the window resizes I just want the triangle to change it's width so that it still fills the whole screen width (100%) but not it's height.
At the moment the whole thing looks like this (triangle colored black only for demonstration purposes) which judging by the looks is what I want to achieve:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```css
.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.triangle {
  border-top: 40px solid black;
  border-left: 950px solid transparent;
  border-right: 950px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 107px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8372wcs/

My problems:

- I can't figure out how to make the triangle take 100% of the screen size (I'm using a width in pixels at the moment).
- I can't figure out how to make the triangle stick to the exact bottom of the div (here I'm also using a pixel value at the moment).
- I can neither figure out how to resize the triangle responsively nor how to maintain it's height while doing so (I tried serveral tutorials).

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/L8372wcs/1/

---

**CSS** (Relevant changes)

```
.top {
    ...
    position: relative;
}

.triangle {

    border-top: 40px solid black;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
    ...
    bottom: -40px;
}
```

1. The left and right borders are defined with viewport units (since your div is 100% wide). The triangle is responsive (try to resize the viewport)
2. The triangle position is defined with `bottom: -40px;` (instead of top) and its parent has `position: relative;` This will ensure that the triangle will be positioned always just below the green element (until the top border of the triangle is `40px` tall)

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: there is one issue with the `vw` approach : when the content is high enough for a vertical scrollbar, a horizontal scrollbar also appears

Comment: good point, but unfortunately the borders can't be set with `%` unit. I will think about it

Comment: using `overflow:hidden;` could solve the issue but the triangle would be slightly cut on the side

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was on vacation.
Thanks a lot for the awesome solution and the effort you put into it (to all you other guys as well)!

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to use an **[inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg)** with the polygon element.

This way, it's width can be set to 100% and it's height can be controled independently with CSS thx to the [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) svg attribute.

In the following example, the height of the triangle is fixed to 40px but you can **make the height rezise according the width** by removing the CSS height property and the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

```css
.top {
    position:relative;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.triangle {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="triangle" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <polygon points="0 0 100 0 50 10"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

You can also style the triangle (fill colors, border, opacity...) as derired either with CSS or with attributes in the SVG element. Here is an example with CSS :

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  fill: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <svg class="triangle" viewbox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polygon points="0 0 100 0 50 10" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vw` unit (viewport width).

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8372wcs/2/).

Answer (score 2):

**I can't figure out how to make the triangle take 100% of the screen size (I'm using a width in pixels at the moment).**

This can be done by using `vw` as the units for the borders creating the triangle. As the body has a `margin` (`8px` in Chrome) use `calc(50vw - 8px)` to accommodate for it.

**I can't figure out how to make the triangle stick to the exact bottom of the div (here I'm also using a pixel value at the moment).**

Position `.triangle` relative to `.top` by adding `position: relative;` to `.top` then add `top: 100%` to `.triangle` to always place it at the bottom of `.top`.

**I can neither figure out how to resize the triangle responsively nor how to maintain it's height while doing so (I tried serveral tutorials).**

The `vw` unit will make the triangle responsive.

```css
.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.triangle {
  border-left: calc(50vw - 8px) solid transparent;
  border-right: calc(50vw - 8px) solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid black;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Triangle can also be created with [`linear-gradient`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#linear-gradients):

```css
.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%) no-repeat left top / 50% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%) no-repeat right top / 50% 100%;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Chrome does not produce smooth results but expect this to be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit?

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.top {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.triangle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    border-top: 30px solid black;
}
```